# what is the difference between MPI_Probe and MPI_Get_count in mpi

Tags: c, mpi

I've found that MPI_Probe is used to find the message size, and MPI_Get_count to find the message length. 
What's the difference between message length and message size?
Aren't they both same?
Moreover what's the count parameter in the MPI_Send or MPI_Recv signifies?
Does it implies the no of times the same message will be sent/recieve from Process x to process y?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While `MPI_Probe` may be used to find the size of a message you have to use `MPI_Get_count` to get that size.  `MPI_Probe` returns a `status` which is a data structure providing information about the message, including its source, tag and size.  But to get that size you call `MPI_Get_count` with the status as an argument.

I'm not sure where you've got the terms 'message size' and 'message length' from or how you have come to the idea that they are different.  For me the message size is simply the number (usually called `count`) of instances of one of the MPI datatypes; so one message might carry 6 MPI_Integers, another might carry 1024 MPI_Reals, and so forth.

When used as an argument in `MPI_Send` or `MPI_Recv` the `count` is the number of instances of a datatype in the message -- that datatype is in both procedures the next argument after the `count`.