# Why does you need to find the lenght with MPI_probe while you also indicate the message lenth in the send/receive functions?

Tags: c, performance, parallel-processing, mpi

The following code is a implementation of MPI. There is a message with increasing length that is being sent en returned. With each iteration the number of elements of the message increase.

There are 2 statements in the code that I don't understand.

```
    MPI_Probe(MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    MPI_Get_count(&status, MPI_INT, &numberOfElementsReceived);
```

On the first sight it looked not necessary in order to pass the message forward and back, but when I deteted it and compiled my code, it gave an error.

I also checked this post:  [what is the difference between MPI_Probe and MPI_Get_count in mpi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12111232/what-is-the-difference-between-mpi-probe-and-mpi-get-count-in-mpi)

*""While MPI_Probe may be used to find the size of a message you have to use MPI_Get_count to get that size. MPI_Probe returns a status which is a data structure providing information about the message, including its source, tag and size. But to get that size you call MPI_Get_count with the status as an argument.""*

Why is it important to know the size and length of the message with the functions MPI_Probe and MPI_Get_Count? This is confusing me because you already describe the number of elements you send and receive in the MPI_Send and MPI_Recv functions.

```
for (message_size = 1; message_size <= MAX_ARRAY_SIZE; message_size <<= 1)
{
//  Use a loop to vary the message size
if (myRank == 0)
{
    double startTime, endTime;
    numberOfElementsToSend = message_size;
    
    printf("Rank %2.1i: Sending %i elements\n", myRank, numberOfElementsToSend);

    //  Measure the time spent in MPI communication
    //       (use the variables startTime and endTime)
     startTime = MPI_Wtime();

    MPI_Send(myArray, numberOfElementsToSend, MPI_INT, 1, 0,
        MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Probe(MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    MPI_Get_count(&status, MPI_INT, &numberOfElementsReceived);

    MPI_Recv(myArray, numberOfElementsReceived, MPI_INT, 1, 0,
        MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE); 
    
    endTime = MPI_Wtime();
    
    printf("Rank %2.1i: Received %i elements\n",
        myRank, numberOfElementsReceived);

    printf("Ping Pong took %f seconds\n", endTime - startTime);
}
else if (myRank == 1)
{
    // Probe message in order to obtain the amount of data
    MPI_Probe(MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    MPI_Get_count(&status, MPI_INT, &numberOfElementsReceived);

    MPI_Recv(myArray, numberOfElementsReceived, MPI_INT, 0, 0,
        MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);

    printf("Rank %2.1i: Received %i elements\n",
        myRank, numberOfElementsReceived);
    
    numberOfElementsToSend = numberOfElementsReceived;

    printf("Rank %2.1i: Sending back %i elements\n",
        myRank, numberOfElementsToSend);

    MPI_Send(myArray, numberOfElementsToSend, MPI_INT, 0, 0,
        MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    
}
```

}

Comment: if you do not know the size of the next message to be received, you can use these two subroutines, and then `malloc()` the receive buffer and `MPI_Recv()`. But If you try to receive less data than sent, then your application will abort.

Comment: I didn't show that in the snippet, but the max array_size is 1<<26. The memory was already allocated before the loop. But every iteration less data is sent and received and the program doesn't abort. How is that possible? @gillesGouaillardet

Comment: The problem only occurs if the data sent is larger than what `MPI_Recv()` is willing to accept. Your case is the other way around and it is fine. In your case, you can skip `MPI_Probe()` and use a `MPI_Status` instead of `MPI_STATUS_IGNORE` to retrieve how much data has been received.

Comment: I'm afraid you are doing those MPI exercises outside their context. The point of this one is to teach you how to receive messages when the size is not known in advance. The example is indeed contrived because you know that there is an outer loop that doubles the message size on each iteration, but the reason the loop is there is that both rank 0 and rank 1 should loop through the exactly same number of iterations. A cleaner variant will have two loops, one in each rank.